# How Go copy and Sort an Array in Java. I am given this array [10,5,42,17,108]. I am to copy the array Then try to Sort ist

Tags: java, arrays

1ˋˋˋ
2.ˋPublic class Sorter{ˋ
3.
4.ˋPlublic int[] sort(toSort){ˋ
5.}ˋ
6.ˋReturn ;ˋ
7.}
8.ˋˋˋ

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array= {10,5,42,17,108};
int[] array2=new int[array.length];
for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++) {
    array2[x]=array[x];
}
Arrays.sort(array2);
for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++) {
    System.out.print(array2[x]+" ");
}
```

To copy an array you can create another of the same length and then go through the first one adding the values ​​to the second. Then the function sort of Arrays is used and you get a sorted array